# How to add date value in dynamically created date field using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need one help. I have one `json array` and I need to add some date value present inside that `JSON array` in dynamically created date field using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
$depdate=[  
   {  
      "sett_id":"270",
      "sett_name":"Car",
      "sett_type":"vtypes",
      "id":"6",
      "dep_dates":"31-10-2018,07-11-2018,14-11-2018,21-11-2018,28-11-2018",
      "vehicle_type":"270"
   },
   {  
      "sett_id":"271",
      "sett_name":"Bus",
      "sett_type":"vtypes",
      "id":"7",
      "dep_dates":"01-11-2018,08-11-2018,22-11-2018,15-11-2018,29-11-2018,06-12-2018",
      "vehicle_type":"271"
   }]
```

This is my `JSON array` value which has key `dep_dates` and it contains all dates with comma separate. I am explaining the code below.

```
<?php foreach ($depdate as $key => $value) { 
                $dep_date=explode(",",$value['dep_dates']);
                //print_r($dep_date);exit;
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key+1; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['sett_name']; ?></td>
                <td><div class="input_fields_wrap<?php echo $key+1; ?> form-horizontal"><div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><input type="text" name="ddate_<?php echo $value['sett_id']; ?>[]" value="" class="depdate<?php echo $key+1; ?> form-control"  style="width:280px;max-width:280px;display:inline-block"><button type="button" class="add_field_button<?php echo $key+1; ?> btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-top: -5px;min-height: 30px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div></div></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="vid_<?php echo $value['sett_id']; ?>_id" value="<?php echo $value['sett_id']; ?>" >
              </tr>
              <script>
                $(function(){
                  var addButton = $('.add_field_button<?php echo $key+1; ?>');
                  var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap<?php echo $key+1; ?>');
                  var nowTemp = new Date();
                  var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
                  $(addButton).click(function(){
                    $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><input type="text" name="ddate_<?php echo $value['sett_id']; ?>[]" value="" class="depdate<?php echo $key+1; ?> form-control"  style="width:280px;max-width:280px;display:inline-block"/><button type="button" class="remove_field<?php echo $key+1; ?> btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-top: -5px;min-height: 30px;"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div>'); //add input box
                    $('.depdate<?php echo $key+1; ?>').datepicker({
                      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                      onRender: function(date) { 
                        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ''; 
                      } 
                    });
                  })
                  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field<?php echo $key+1; ?>', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent('div').remove();
                  })
                  $('.depdate<?php echo $key+1; ?>').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                    onRender: function(date) { 
                      return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ''; 
                    }
                  });
                })
              </script>
              <?php } ?>
```

Here I have one date field with `+` button and when user will click on it new field is creating. Here My requirement is if `dep_dates` has any value it will converted into array and the date field will created dynamically as per no of date value and those value will append into the field. Actually this is the `update` feature. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost close, you want to fill data from `$depdate` json to the `datepicker` textbox.

Solution :

1. Get `sett_id` from PHP and Read json value for the same
2. Convert `dep_dates` into array
3. Set that array's value getting total `datepicker` applied dynamically

Please check HTML code below (Read comment line):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $depdate = [
    {
        "sett_id": "270",
        "sett_name": "Car",
        "sett_type": "vtypes",
        "id": "6",
        "dep_dates": "31-10-2018,07-11-2018,14-11-2018,21-11-2018,28-11-2018",
        "vehicle_type": "270"
    },
    {
        "sett_id": "271",
        "sett_name": "Bus",
        "sett_type": "vtypes",
        "id": "7",
        "dep_dates": "01-11-2018,08-11-2018,22-11-2018,15-11-2018,29-11-2018,06-12-2018",
        "vehicle_type": "271"
    }]
});

$(function () {
    var addButton = $('.add_field_button1');
    var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap1');
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
            
    $(addButton).click(function () {
        var sett_id = 0;///Apply PHP code here
        var myDatesArr = $depdate[sett_id].dep_dates.split(',');///Read json file and convert date into array
        var crrDatePosition = $('.input_fields_wrap1 .datepicker').length;//Get total existing datepicker
        $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><input type="text" name="ddate_' + sett_id + '" value="' + myDatesArr[crrDatePosition] + '" class="depdate1 datepicker form-control"  style="width:280px;max-width:280px;display:inline-block"/><button type="button" class="remove_field1 btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-top: -5px;min-height: 30px;">-</button></div>'); //add input box
        $('.depdate1').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            onRender: function (date) {
                return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        });
    })
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field1', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
    $('.depdate1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Something <input type="hidden" name="vid_1_id" value="1"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="input_fields_wrap1 form-horizontal">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <input type="text" name="ddate_1" value="" class="depdate1 form-control" style="width:280px;max-width:280px;display:inline-block">
                    <button type="button" class="add_field_button1 btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-top: -5px;min-height: 30px;">Click here to add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see `var sett_id = 0;` is applied static by zero, you need to change by its PHP value.

Comment: Its one solution but it might create confusion to user because its one `update functinality.'